# How to make a second page in a crystal report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to design a report which has two pages or more, I want to put data in page 1 and some other data in page 2. Because when I tried to add section like `Section2(Detailsb)` it doesn't worked. I'm using visual studio 2008. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Section2(Detailsb)` in second page then

```
go to --> section expert --> check option new page after
```

This will print the details in new page.